# How to add custom paramater in error object lb4?

Tags: node.js, api, strongloop, lookback

I am using strongloop 4 (lb4). I am facing one issue that in error object I need to one more custom parameter in the error object.

I want it on the global level. On every error, I want to add that custom parameter in every error message.

In loopback4 global error handling is done by **src/sequence.ts**.

Suppose the error message object is.

```
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 400,
    "name": "xyz",
    "message": "firstName is required"
  }
}
```

I want error object output like.

```
{
  "error": {
    "customParam" : "customParam",
    "statusCode": 400,
    "name": "xyz",
    "message": "firstName is required"
  }
}
```

Comment: Post your code and check out how to ask your question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Updated , Can you please check.

Answer (score 2):

*Cross-posting the answer I gave on GitHub in [https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/1867#issuecomment-434247807](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/1867#issuecomment-434247807_)*

Building HTTP error responses is a tricky business. It's easy to get it wrong and open your application to attacks.

In LoopBack (both 3.x and 4.x), we use our [strong-error-handler](https://github.com/strongloop/strong-error-handler) middleware to take care of this. See [Handling Errors](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Sequence.html#handling-errors) in our docs.

Here are the important security constraints to keep in mind:

> In production mode, `strong-error-handler` omits details from error responses to prevent leaking sensitive information:
>
> - For 5xx errors, the output contains only the status code and the status name from the HTTP specification.
> - For 4xx errors, the output contains the full error message (`error.message`) and the contents of the `details` property (`error.details`) that `ValidationError` typically uses to provide machine-readable details about validation problems. It also includes `error.code` to allow a machine-readable error code to be passed through which could be used, for example, for translation.
>
> In debug mode, `strong-error-handler` returns full error stack traces and internal details of any error objects to the client in the HTTP responses.

Now that I have warned you, LoopBack 4 makes it very easy to format the error messages your way. Just provide a custom implementation of the Sequence action `reject`. See [Customizing Sequence Actions](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Sequence.html#customizing-sequence-actions) in our docs, it explain how to create a custom `send` action. The solution for `reject` is pretty much the same, you just need a different signature for the action function.

```
export class CustomRejectProvider implements Provider<Reject> {
  // ...
  action({request, response}: HandlerContext, error: Error) {
    // handle the error and send back the error response
    // "response" is an Express Response object
  }
}
```

Caveat: some errors thrown by LB4 have only `code` set, these errors need a bit of pre-processing to decide what HTTP status code they should trigger. (For example, the error code `ENTITY_NOT_FOUND` should be mapped to the status code `404`). The built-in `reject` action does not yet expose this pre-processing for consumption by custom reject actions. It's an oversight on our side, l created a new issue https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/1942 to keep track of that.

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding error object into new object.

```
                       let error = new Error();
                        error.name = 'Invalid_OTP_AttemptsError';
                        error.status = 422;
                        error.message = 'You’ve exceeded the maximum number of One-Time Password (OTP) attempts';
                        let data={...error};
                        data.retryCount=foundMb.retryCount
                        data.resendCount=foundMb.resendCount
                        return callback(null,data);
```